# Check in current index of array is what object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview

So I have a array:

`var allArray: [AnyObject] = []`

That array contains multiple `UIImageView`'s and multiple [Player](https://github.com/piemonte/Player)'s.
What I want to accomplish is that I want to detect is something like:

`if allArray[0].object = UIImageView` -> Do some code if current is image

`if allArray[0].object = Player` -> Do some code if current is player

I hope you guys understand what my problem is. I want to detect if `[0]` in the array is `UIImageView` or `Player`

Comment: Do you *really* need an array of `AnyObjects`? What does it represent? You're just throwing away type safety – which goes against the Swift way of doing things. I would generally prefer to use an array of elements that conform to a given protocol, or a type erasure in order to wrap your elements in. You may also be able to split these up into two arrays depending on what you're using them for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the type cast operator [`as`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) to check the type of object in the array:

```
if let object = allArray[0] as? UIImageView { ...

if let object = allArray[0] as? Player { ...

for object in allArray {
  if let object = object as? UIImageView {
    ...
  }
  else if let object = object as? Player {
    ...
  }
}
```

Plus, you might want to use [`.first`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/firstObject) instead of `[0]` as the latter one throws an exception if array is empty:

```
if let object = allArray.first as? UIImageView { ...
```

Please see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID340) for more information about *type checking* and *type casting*.

Comment: Uhm witch one should i be using?

Comment: `if let object = allArray.first as? ...` is the safest one.